# Mesh boolean in Geometry Nodes is slow, any alternatives or workarounds available?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, node-editor, geometry-nodes, text-object

I wanted some basic boolean operations for a few title animations. Here's one where I use a pie animation to reveal the text underneath

[image]

But using Mesh boolean makes the scene lag so much.

Is there a workaround or an alternative I can use?

I tried using holdout shader, but it makes the bg completely transparent and for me using compositor is not an option.

Comment: You should be able to control the transparency in shader nodes by using polar coordinates. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7gFzuPG7Kc

Comment: I watched the tutorial you linked. How am I supposed to use this? The pie mesh is more like a disc rather than a sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the pie in shader nodes by using the angle component of polar coordinates, like so :

[image]

The blend file contains the entire polar coordinate node group but I stripped it down to the angle component for the screen capture.

[image]